# Two different width borders on 3 sides

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I had this code to create a double border off different widths, but i need it to only show on the left,top and right sides. This is fine with the border property but not possible with outline as it doesn't share the same border-left etc

```
border: double 4px black;
outline: solid 3px black;
```

any help would be great

Comment: Why not remove the outline and instead create a nested element inside of the element you already have with the second border style you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not remove the outline and instead create a nested element inside of the element?

You can do like this:

Create nested elements in HTML:

```
<div class="big">
        <div class="small">Some text Here.....</div>
</div>
```

Then apply CSS:

```
.big{
      border: 5px solid green;
      border-bottom: none;
    }
.small{
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: none;
        margin: 2px;
    }
```

No need to use the outline.

Comment: create a js fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`box-shadow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) instead of `outline` - see demo below:

```css
div {
  line-height: 20px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 0 0 black,  /* left */
              3px 0 0 0 black,  /* right */
              3px -3px 0 0 black, /* top */
              -3px -3px 0 0 black; /* top */
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create nested elements with their own id's

```
<div id="outer-border">
   <div id="inner-border"></div>
</div>
```

Then set the correct CSS properties for those elements, for example something like:

```
#outer-border{border-bottom: none}
#inner-border{border-bottom: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using gradient to create the second border.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-bottom:none;
  padding:3px; /*control the distance between border*/
  padding-bottom:0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) top  /100% 4px,
    linear-gradient(green,green) left /4px  100%,
    linear-gradient(green,green) right/4px  100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Another idea using pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-bottom:none;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:3px;
  left:3px;
  right:3px;
  bottom:0;
  border: solid 4px green;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.st1, .st2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.st1 {
    outline: solid 3px black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.st2 {
border-left-color: black;
border-left-style: double;
border-left-width: 4px;
border-top-color: black;
border-top-style: double;
border-top-width: 4px;
border-right-color: black;
border-right-style: double;
border-right-width: 4px;
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
right: -1px;
top: -1px;
bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="st1"><div class="st2"></div></div>
```

or

```css
.st1, .st2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.st1 {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.st2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="st1"><div class="st2">test</div></div>
```